# How can I let members edit their relationships?

Tags: civimember, relationships, user-dashboard, backdrop

We have organizational memberships - each organization can have up to five individuals who are listed as members.  We do this via the membership "Relationship Type" feature, and it works well.

However, competing platforms have a dashboard that allows the contact person for an organization add/remove the individual members that should be part of the record.  How can this be implemented with CiviCRM?

Civi 4.7.31, Backdrop 1.9.2 - so Views/Webform/etc. are all options.  It's acceptable for a member administrator to search contact names in the database.  Writing custom code is an option if there's a simple-ish way to do this.

Comment: You're just referring to allowing org admins permission for editing the CiviCRM contacts of the members, nothing related to Backdrop users, right?

Comment: Correct @Laryn-CEDC.org. I'm stating the CMS in case CMS-side modules present a solution.

Comment: Curious if you ever found (or made) an answer to this one?

Comment: Nope, sorry @Laryn-CEDC.org.  The client lost interest.

Answer (score 2):

I've done something similar with Views, VBO and a custom action.  There is an "Add relationship with contact" action in VBO but for more control over the action you can [write a custom action](https://www.drupal.org/node/2052067).

In my case, the view is of Civi contacts with one of several relationship types to the org. The action is a 'Set as Correspondent' button.  Only one person at a time holds the Correspondent relationship with the org so the action uses `civicrm_api3()` to find and end any current Correspondent relationships, create a new relationship between the selected contact and org and create an activity for info purposes.

Your action could do something similar but check there are no more than 4 existing relationships of that type before creating a new one.

Comment: This is the missing piece I'm looking for! Do you have code you can share for your "Set as Correspondent" action?

Comment: nudge - did anything get shared re this custom action? ;-)

Answer (score 1):

I have a similar requirement for a project. This piece is not yet in active development, but I anticipate building an Angular form (probably based on crmUiWizard) to allow management of relationships and possibly also a limited subset of contact details. In my case it's (probably) NOT acceptable for a member administrator to search contact names in the database (without limitations); might need to rely on the dedupe feature to allow entry of new contacts without creating a mess.

Answer (score 0):

It might be possible to do this via a View that lists people that are linked to the contact person's Org and provides customized links from the view to a webform (passing contact IDs via URL to populate the webform). You may also need the [Relationship Permissions ACL extension](https://civicrm.org/extensions/relationship-permissions-acls) and have these relationships set up to grant editing permissions.

e.g. If you have a view that is pulling the current user (contact person with permissions to add/edit), you can use the View to also get the Org and the other members based on relationships, then feed them into a Webform with CiviCRM functionality enabled, feeding the contact IDs into the webform using the URL. ("If the url contains e.g. cid1=123, it will be used to pre-populate this contact (takes precidence over other default values).")

You could set up the form to only allow input for 6 contacts (the org and 5 members) and specify their relationships in the webform/civicrm settings, you can feed the contact IDs if they exist, or allow new contacts to be created if they don't.

Comment: I just had a thought that might solve the issue in terms of a max number of member listings and edited above.

Answer (score 0):

Set up a View that shows the logged in person the Org they are related to, and the Indivs related to that Org. Provide an 'update' button/link to load the url of a webform where they can they edit or add new Contacts.

I can probably add more if I understand at what point this approach is problematic (eg Backdrop has Webform but not Webform-CiviCRM?)

Comment: How does one create a new relationship from the View?

Comment: Provide an 'add another' link in the view that takes them to webform eg in View Header or Footer - the link would have eg cid1 value in url

Comment: But given your experience in such things i am sure i must be misunderstanding the requirement. happy to skype share if that helps